# iPod library: obtain the filename of a media item

Tags: iphone, file, filesystems

I have several questions regarding filenames and the "iPod Library".

1. I understand I can retrieve
   MPMediaItems from the "iPod
   Library".  How may I get the
   filename of a MPMediaItem?  (I only
   need to read the filenames, not save to or otherwise modify 
   the library.)
2. When an mp3 is added to the iPod
       library (via iTunes), does it keep its filename?
3. May I obtain a list of all filenames
       within the iPod library?  i.e. can
       contentsOfDirectoryAtPath be used to
       list filenames from the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Not just that, you should also note that even on a jailbroken iphone, the media file names are changed to some random 4-5 char strings.

Even if you get the real file name, you can't do anything much with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the URL of the item via the **MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL** property.

```
-(void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    NSArray* items = [ mediaItemCollection items ];
    if ( [ items count ] )
    {
        MPMediaItem* mediaItem = [ items objectAtIndex:0 ];
        NSURL* url = [ mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL ];
        NSLog( @"%@", url );
    }
    [ self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
}
```

It will typically yield urls in the form of:
ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-5938525213358316745